# Computation using PHP from MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new at ***PHP*** and
I want to know how can I create an *sql* statement that will compute for percentage
from my database table using ***PHP***.

Example is: the value from my database is 10000 and I want to get its 0.50%

Sorry for this statement. I dont know the technical term. Hope you can help me. Thanks!

I dont know if this is correct. Please understand. :D

Here's my code:

```
<?
$result   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_payment where amount");

$num_total = ($amount / $num_percent) * 100;
echo $num_total;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

error in your sql syntax

```
$result   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_payment where amount=10000");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$num_total = ($['your column name for computing %'] / $num_percent) * 100;
echo $num_total; 
}
```

Comment: $num_amount = "amount";
$num_percent = "0.50";
$num_total = "";


$result   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_payment where amount=10000");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$num_total = ($['amount'] / $num_percent) * 100;
echo $num_total; 
}
?>

Comment: what do you want to tell ?